# RDS Security Groups Ingress rule

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation, aws-security-group

I'm working on CloudFormation template which includes RDS Database and I wanted to attach security group to RDS. There is a resource [AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-security-group.html)  where I would like to write my own Ingress Rules which allows MySQL traffic from the front end instances by attaching this resource [AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroupIngress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-security-group-ingress.html) but, it doesn't show any properties like "FromPort" , "ToPort" , "Protocol" , etc..

I'm unsure whether the above listed properties will support or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Working with DB Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithSecurityGroups.html):

> A DB security group controls network access to a DB instance that is not inside a VPC.

If you are using a VPC (which should always be the case unless you systems setup many years ago), you should use an [`AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group.html) to control security. It *does* the properties you desire, eg:

```
"InstanceSecurityGroup" : {
   "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
   "Properties" : {
      "GroupDescription" : "Allow http to client host",
      "VpcId" : {"Ref" : "myVPC"},
      "SecurityGroupIngress" : [{
            "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
            "FromPort" : "80",
            "ToPort" : "80",
            "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
         }],
      "SecurityGroupEgress" : [{
         "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
         "FromPort" : "80",
         "ToPort" : "80",
         "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"
      }]
   }
}
```